# confusion in tags on Parts-of-speech.Info

Tags: parts-of-speech

I am using the site [Parts-of-speech.Info](https://parts-of-speech.info/) for the self study but I don't understand what these tags mean.

Below are three screenshots that show the site's part-of-speech tagging for the sentence "Failure must not have permanent affect on a person because only the tough survives". In the first picture, "have" has been tagged as "verb, VB", while "survives" (see the second picture) is tagged as "verb, VBZ":

[image: Screenshot showing that "have" is tagged as "Verb, VB"]

[image: Screenshot showing that "survives" is tagged as "Verb, VBZ"]

[image: Screenshot showing that "permanent" is tagged as "adjective, JJ"]

Comment: It does warn you that "the grammar and orthography are correct" - is it in your example?

Comment: No I think I should have used effect in place of affect. Permanent is adjective so it should be followed by noun not a verb. @SolarMike Am I right?

Comment: survive or survives ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are tags to represent parts of speech more specifically. For instance VBZ means verb in its third person singular form.

You may visit the page [Alphabetical list of part-of-speech tags used in the Penn Treebank Project](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) to check them.